# How can I correct this sentence? The bellflower is a wildflower that grows in shady fields , in marshes and mountain slopes?

Tags: grammar, american-english

What is the correct form of "the bellflower is a wildflower that grows in shady fields , in marshes and mountain slopes?"

1. the bellflower is a wildflower that grows in shady fields , in
   marshes and **on the mountain slopes**?
2. the bellflower is a
       wildflower that grows in shady fields , in marshes and **the
       mountain**?

Comment: (2) is wrong, because 'in' marshes and 'in' the mountains have different levels of literalness. Compare the absurd zeugma 'He is on a rigid diet and time'. I'd use (1), but I'd drop the unbalanced 'the'.

Comment: They are both grammatical. The second is less acceptable in *stylistic* terms, but that's completely a matter of opinion. (Stylistically speaking, the best noun phrase at the end would be *and on [] **mountains**.* (Or *on [] mountain slopes*.) Note the removal of the article and pluralization of the noun. That would have it exactly match the syntactical form of the other list items.)

Comment: What species of bellflower are you referring to?

Comment: Presumably it doesn't grow only on one particular mountain.